# Can MapBox support many (1000+) MarkerViews?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

My app will, at some times, show a lot of markers on the map. I am just wondering if MapBox is capable of loading all of this without causing performance issues? My current implementation adds 186 markers. Once they were added, panning the map is very slow and laggy. Markers also disappeared when outside of the screen and never gets loaded again when panning back.

This is really frustrating, I am now more inclined to use my original implementation which basically use `MarkerOption`. It works well but I ran into some issues that after clicking multiple times toggling select/deselect marker appearance (I replace the color of icon by replacing icon's bitmap), the marker disappeared, and all the markers I touched.

I am looking on creating my own custom marker instead and try to minimize my use of setIcon if possible. The problem is that I have to deal with bitmaps (I load bitmaps from client's server). I cannot use runtime-styling as suggested.

Also, apologize, I cannot show anymore code/screenshot at this point. The app is nearing completion and I am just optimizing this part of the app.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For this scale, I would advice you to look into using runtime styling with a symbollayer.

Comment: I cannot do runtime styling as we are working on a different requirement. We are using our pin (look and feel). We are hosting them on a different server. I cannot force client to login into MapBox studio and do editing himself. We have provided our own CMS for that.